# End to end encrypt a socket.io chat application

Tags: socket.io, public-key-encryption

I am building a socket.io based chat application.

What options do I have to implement end to end encryption over the text & data/files?

Note: I need to support one-to-one and group chats.

Any open source ready to use implementation specifically for socket.io? Googled it but no luck.

If not, then any hints to to implement something of my own?

Comment: by 'end to end' encryption do you mean SSL? Websockets have a secure version, WSS that can provide SSL on the protocol. Or are you talking user to user encryption (similar to bleep.me)?

Comment: @d3l33t : Well SSL will be in place as per the client requirements. Never used bleep.me but Whatsapp end to end encryption is an example I can give to explain what encryption I am looking for.

Comment: sorry. meant bleep.pm

Comment: check out https://keybase.io/

Comment: If SSL is already in place you don't have any further requirement.

Comment: @EJP AFAIK, SSL is good for "point to point" encryption and not the "end to end" encryption. With just SSL, server can still look into the messages before relaying to the destination. Correct  me if I'm wrong though. And you know, all the fuss about WhatsApp end to end encryption everyone is asking to implement it somehow :)

Comment: @user207421 May I ask why just SSL would suffice to provide "end-to-end" encryption? The reason I am asking is because I am building a small prototype chat application. I glimpsed through the documentation for Signal Protocol and was wondering if it is too much burden to undertake for a small prototype. My understanding of encryption is quite fundamental and I would be glad if you could elaborate on what possible security hardening will an end-to-end system provide over traditional HTTPS or in this case WSS?

Answer (score 27):

The end-to-end encryption used in WhatsApp and Facebook Messenger is powered by [the Signal protocol](https://signal.org/) (which have its own chat app), if you are using Socket.io with Javascript, you can easily use the [javascript version](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-javascript) of the Signal protocol. Just follow the readme to encrypt your data and use Socket.io to send it to the other hand, then decrypt the received data.

The end-to-end encryption used by Telegram is [MTProto](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto), developed by the Telegram team. Like Signal, it's open source so you can find the source code on Github.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for providing really good overview of e2e encryption used by other apps.

Comment: It seems it's no longer maintained because they now have a typescript version: https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal